# core data class model using NSObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

Does every object that I want to store in core data have to inherit from NSManagedObject? So if something is an NSObject then it is guaranteed 100% that, that particular object is not stored in core data? The issue is that I have downloaded this project and it has this model for an object, however the object class is a NSObject, so I am confused whether this is actually stored in core data or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.  However, `NSManagedObject` inherits from `NSObject`.

From [NSManagedObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html):

> NSManagedObject is a generic class that implements all the basic behavior required of a Core Data model object. It is not possible to use instances of direct subclasses of NSObject (or any other class not inheriting from NSManagedObject) with a managed object context. You may create custom subclasses of NSManagedObject, although this is not always required. If no custom logic is needed, a complete object graph can be formed with NSManagedObject instances.

Comment: so you're saying an NSObject can also be stored in core data?

Comment: No, but I'm saying that making your NSObjects into NSManagedObjects is possible and probably fairly simple.